# PySpark Create DataFrame With Float TypeError

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark-sql, pyspark

I have Data Sets as Below:

[image]

I am using PySpark to parse the data and create a DataFrame later using below code:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

def parseInput(line):
    fields = line.split(',')
    stationID=fields[0]
    entryType=fields[2]
    temperature= fields[3]*0.3
    return Row(stationID,entryType,temperature)

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("MinTemperatures").getOrCreate()
lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile("data/1800.csv")
temperatures = lines.map(parseInput)
minTemps=temperatures.filter(lambda x:x[1]=='TMIN')
df = spark.createDataFrame(minTemps)
```

I got below error:

```
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Obviously, if I remove 0.3 out of `temperature= fields[3]*0.3`, the create DataFrame work. How can I return the `temperature` with float number and some basic math operation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try  temperature= float(fields[3])*0.3

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 1):

You can read the file without multiplication first and then cast it to Type Double, do the multiplication finally.

I assume your csv file have header.
The following code is for casting:

```py
data = data.withColumn("COLUMN_NAME", data["COLUMN_NAME"].cast("double"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer